# como pasar una imagen de un modal por ajax con laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

tengo una tabla y en cada fila tengo un boton para editar la imagen de la fila que corresponde y otros datos mas de la fila, el problema es que se manda todos los datos a mi controlador pero el dato de la imagen no se manda y no se cual se la razon,eso solo pasa en el modal, por que he usado lo mismo en una pagina normal y si pasa.

VISTA (MODAL)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 b-r"><h3 class="m-t-none m-b">CREAR SLIDER</h3>

                            <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

                            {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST','route' => ['inicio.actualizarSler','id'], 'files' => true,'id'=>'form-editarslider']) !!}

                            <input type="hidden" id="idslider" name="idslider">

                            <div class="form-group"><label>Titulo</label> <input type="text" id="tituloEditar" name="tituloEditar" placeholder="Ingrese titulo" class="form-control"></div>
                            <div class="form-group"><label>Subtitulo</label> <input type="text" id="subtituloEditar" name="subtituloEditar" placeholder="Ingrese subtitulo" class="form-control"></div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="idMenu" value="{{ $menu->idMenu  }}">

                            <div class="form-group"><label>URL</label> <input type="text" id="descripcionEditar" name="descripcionEditar" placeholder="Ingrese enlace" class="form-control"></div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::file('rutaImagenSlider',['id'=>'file-rutaImagenSlider']) !!}
                                    <img name="rutaImagenSlider"  src="" id="rutaImagenSlider" style="width: 50%;"/>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                           {!! Form::close() !!}

                            <div>
                                <button onclick="guardarSlider();" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs" type="submit"><strong>REGISTRAR</strong></button>



            </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

RUTA:

```
  Route::post('actualizarSler/{cod}', 'MenuController@actualizarSler')->name('inicio.actualizarSler');
```

Controlador:

```
public function actualizarSler(Request $request)
    {

        $slider = Detalle_imagen::find($request->cod);


        $slider->titulo = $request->tituloEditar;
        $slider->subtitulo = $request->subtituloEditar;
        $slider->enlace = $request->descripcionEditar;
    if(isset($request->rutaImagenSlider)){
        $file = $request->file('rutaImagenSlider');
        $slider->rutaImagen =  $file->getClientOriginalName();
        \Storage::disk('local')->put( $slider->rutaImagen,  \File::get($file));
    }

   $slider->save();

    return response()->json($slider->rutaImagen);
}
```

JS y ajax

```
function mostrarEditarSlider(id,titulo,subtitulo,enlace,ruta_imagen) {


        $("#tituloEditar").val(titulo);
        $("#subtituloEditar").val(subtitulo);
        $("#descripcionEditar").val(enlace);
        $("#idslider").val(id);

      document.getElementById("rutaImagenSlider").src = '../../storage/'+ruta_imagen;
        $("#file-rutaImagenSlider").change(function () {
            readURL(this, 'rutaImagenSlider');
            readURLin(this, 'salvacion');
        });

       $("#exampleModal").modal();



 }


    function guardarSlider() {

        var form =  $("#form-editarslider");

       var urles = form.attr('action').replace('id',$("#idslider").val());
       var formdata = form.serialize();



        $.post({
            url: urles,
            data:formdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            }


        })


}


function readURL(input, id) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#' + id).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

pdt: SI PASAN LOS DEMAS DATOS SOLO EL DE LA IMAGEN NO PASA

Comment: Intenta cambiar el nombre del campo de tipo archivo ya que coincide con la imagen que tiene en la línea de abajo y después me dices.

 {!! Form::file('**rutaImagenSlider**',['id'=>'file-rutaImagenSlider']) !!}
                                    <img name="**rutaImagenSlider**"  src="" id="rutaImagenSlider" style="width: 50%;"/>

Comment: no funciona es mas lo borre igual no pasa